# Completely disable auto run of Jest test runner in Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, jestjs, puppeteer

I have some sets of Jest test cases that run Puppeteer browser tests.

I have tried these test runners

- [Jest (vscode-jest)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest)
- [Jest Test Explorer (Jest Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-test-explorer)
- [Jest Runner (vscode-jest-runner)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner)

To me, I like Jest Test Explorer the most but it always auto-start running test cases.
As you can imagine, a lot of Chrome browser instances get launched when I open a project with VS Code.

I found some configurations but they cannot prevent auto-run test cases.

- `"testExplorer.onStart": "reset"`, or set to null
- `"testExplorer.onReload": "reset"`, or set to null

FYI, an example UI of Jest Test Explorer
[image]

Jest (`vscode-jest`) is a good runner but I can't stop auto-run with these settings as well.

- `"jest.runAllTestsFirst": false,`
- `"jest.autoEnable": false,`
- `"jest.showCoverageOnLoad": false`

Therefore, right now Jest Runner (vscode-jest-runner) is the only runner that does not auto-start unit tests.

In addition, if you have any other test runners to suggest, please let me know.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You're not the only one with this problem! I'm so annoyed by [Tridactyl](https://github.com/tridactyl/tridactyl)'s WebDriverIO tests launching every time I open VScode, and for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to make them stop. ;_;

Comment: Hi @ELLIOTTCABLE. Until now, I still don't know how to fix it. ^^

Answer (score 78):

For `orta.vscode-jest` extension, I added the configuration below in `settings.json`. You can open `settings.json` by doing `Command + Shift + P` (Ctrl + Shift + P on Windows), typing `settings JSON` and selecting `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`.

```
"jest.autoRun": {
    "onStartup": []
}
```

Or you can simply add:

```
"jest.autoRun": {}
```

If you want to run all tests on startup, add `all-tests` to the `onStartup` array:

```
"jest.autoRun": {
    "onStartup": ["all-tests"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

Command + Shift + P  -> typing SETTINGS.JSON  -> Preferences: Open Workspace settings ( JSON ).
And add 
"jest.autoRun": {}


Otherwise it will open settings.json file in read only mode.

Comment: Thanks @MishhubMohammed. I've updated the answer to use `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`. I suppose `Default` and `Workspace` settings work too.

Comment: thank you! leaving it empty `"jest.autoRun": {}` didn't work for me, but providing an empty `onStartup` array did

Answer (score 33):

I just set this simple option into the VS Code's ***`settings.json`***:

```
"jest.autoRun": "false"
```

Comment: This is the best answer; https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest states `autoEnable` should instead use `autoRun`.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: I believe this has changed in a recent update. I now get the following error `invalid autoRun setting "false". Will use default setting instead`

I'm now using the setting `"jest.autoRun": { "watch": false }` instead

Comment: This combined with `"jest.autoRevealOutput": "off"` did the trick! No more error avalanches when I open VSCodium. Thanks.

Comment: i used `"jest.runMode":"on-demand"`, its `"on-save"` by default

Answer (score 27):

At the time of writing (Dec 22) the new way to do this (as per https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#how-to-trigger-the-test-run) is to have the following in the VS Code settings.json. Note I had previously tried the other answers but none worked.

```
  "jest.autoRun": { "watch": false }
```

Comment: The above answer works for me. with version 5.x. 
if you are using version 6.1 and above,  try `"jest.runMode": "on-demand"`.

 `"jest.runMode": {"type": "on-demand", "deferred": true}`  is for< v6.1.0 (replaced by runMode, according to the [Customization Table](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#customization)

Comment: Lol my CPU was 100% and mac got heated pretty bad because the tests were being repeatedly run. This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I made it work by only setting the setting `"jest.autoEnable": false,` on my `settings.json` and restarting VSCode. At least, it is working until now and it hasn't broken yet: [Disable starting Jest automatically](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/352)

To open your `settings.json`:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Then type `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

Comment: Thanks!
I also had to restart my vscode session to make this change apply.

Answer (score 15):

Just put this in settings.json (User)

```
"jest.runMode": "on-demand",
```

Comment: This is the expected "default" as of 2024 and confirm it works as expected in my VS Code workspace.

Comment: Please review existing answers before submitting a new answer. This answer had already been provided by Laszlo Horvath the day prior you posting it. Duplicate answers add noise and can make it harder for the correct answer to get elevated to the top. Further, they’ll typically get deleted—and, if enough of your answers are deleted, you may receive a ban on answering. In your case, you also had enough reputation to upvote previous answers, which is the preferred approach here.

Answer (score 8):

Go to vscode setting.json

You can either add

```
"jest.autoRun": "off"
```

or

```
"jest.autoRun": false
```

both are valid options.
You can checkout the official recommended settings here.

https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#how-to-trigger-the-test-run

> ```
> "jest.autoEnable": false
> ```
>
> is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

2024 update:
`jest.autoRun` became deprecated, use `"jest.runMode": "on-demand"` instead.

[Source](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest?tab=readme-ov-file#runmode)

Answer (score 6):

What it worked for me was:

File -> preferences -> settings. Then under the panel user (in workspace is as well but I am not sure if you need to modify it there as well), go to extensions -> jest.

There you will have a section jest: auto run and you will find a link "edit in settings.json" and modify what is there for this

```json
"jest.autoRun": {
  "watch": false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's some great updated docs [here](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#autoRun)

Migration rule from settings prior to v4:

if "jest.autoEnabled" = false => manual mode: "jest.autoRun": "off"

if "jest.runAllTestsFirst" = false => "jest.autoRun": {"watch": true }

if no customization of the 2 settings and no "jest.autoRun" found =>

Answer (score 4):

First open the jest extension settings.json in the vs code. In the json script add `"jest.autoRun": "off"` to disable test autorun. Below, I add other options as well. 
Source: [Documentation](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#how-to-trigger-the-test-run)

- fully manual
  there will be no automatic test run, users will trigger test run by either command or context-menu.
  Example: "jest.autoRun": "off"
- automatically run tests when test file changed
  the extension will trigger test run for the given test file upon save.
  Example: "jest.autoRun": {"watch": false, "onSave": "test-file"}
- automatically run tests when either test or source file changed:
  the extension will trigger test run for the given test or source file upon save.
  Example: "jest.autoRun": {"watch": false, "onSave": "test-src-file"}

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for to run only the tests in the current file.

Answer (score 4):

```
"jest.autoRun": "off",
"jest.autoRevealOutput": "off",
```

**These are deprecated add the line below**

```
"jest.runMode": "on-demand",
```

Comment: Dupe of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77991857/6243352) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77986898/6243352). In the future, please check existing answers and don't add duplicates. I suggest deleting this to avoid extra noise and maintenance headaches in the thread (someday, this may be deprecated too, yet there'll still be 4+ answers suggesting it). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Setting.json and add this:

```
"jest.runMode": "on-demand"
```

Comment: Please review existing answers before submitting a new answer. This answer has already been provided on three previous answers. Duplicate answers add noise and can make it harder for the correct answer to get elevated to the top. Further, they’ll typically get deleted—and, if enough of your answers are deleted, you may receive a ban on answering. You now have enough reputation to upvote previous answers, which is the preferred approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to settings.json:

```
"jest.autoRun": "off",
"jest.autoRevealOutput": "off",
```

Source: https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#settings